# Area of two intersecting polygons on PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql, intersection

I am trying to calculate the area of two intersecting polygons using PostGIS:

[image]

I've found this solutin:

```
SELECT layer.text,
       layer_2.text,
       sum(st_area(st_Intersection(layer.shape, layer_2.shape))/st_area(layer.shape)*100) as coverage 
FROM layer
LEFT OUTER JOIN layer_2 ON st_intersects(layer.shape, layer_2.shape)
GROUP BY layer.text, layer_2.text
ORDER BY layer.text;
```

result table:

```
| Layer | Layer_2 | coverage |
|-------|---------|----------|
| M1    | 1       | 48.86627 |
| M1    | 2       | 52.42329 |
| M2    | 1       | 22.5502  |
| M2    | 2       | 76.46014 |
| M3    | 3       | 13.24482 |
| M4    | 1       | 57.85429 |
| M4    | 2       | 12.05814 |
| M4    | 3       | 24.51523 |
| M5    |         |          |
```

The result was quite good, although the coverage of M1 feature is higher than 100 (101.2895608). Why did this inaccuracy appear?

I am using shp layer from ArcGIS Pro with 5514 SRID

Comment: Calculations on multiple fractional values in the realm of floating point precision tends to lead to overall imprecisions. However, a very likely reason could be that the intersecting polygons in layer 2 overlap *each other* - try with `ST_Area(ST_Intersection(layer.shape, ST_Union(layer_2.shape)))/ST_Area(layer.shape)*100 AS coverage` (you'd also need to add `layer.shape` to the `GROUP BY`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried this query: `SELECT layer.text, layer_2.text,
    ST_Area(ST_Intersection(layer.shape, ST_Union(layer_2.shape)))/ST_Area(layer.shape)*100 as coverage
FROM layer
LEFT OUTER JOIN layer_2 ON st_intersects(layer.shape, layer_2.shape)
GROUP BY layer.shape, layer.text, layer_2.text
ORDER BY layer.text;` But the result is identical.

Comment: The test you have done (in comments) ensures the two `polygon 1` doesn't overlap each others, but it does not prevent `polygon 1` and `polygon 2` to overlap each others.

Comment: Your final sentence doesn't make any sense. Shapefile is a different format than PostGIS, and the software used to access the shapefile is not germane. The coordinate reference of the PostGIS geometry should be mentioned in the Question.